# How to etract string from a webpage and put it in a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I found software called mecab that basically read a string and categorize the words into noun, verb, etc. What I'm trying to do is using a Google Search API to put the search function on my page so whenever I look up a location, e.g. Oxford street, a number of results will be displayed and mecab will take each of these result individually and do its job.

What I'm stuck at is I don't know how to feed these results to mecab.

Here are the codes:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyBX85AAhYSkh66lk8i2VBSqVJSY_462zGM"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function OnLoad()
  {
      // Create Search Control
      var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

      // Add searcher to Search Control
      searchControl.addSearcher( new google.search.WebSearch() );

      searchControl.draw( document.getElementById( 'content' ) );

      // Execute search
      searchControl.execute( '新宿' );

  }


  // Load Google Search API
  google.load( 'search', '1' );

  google.setOnLoadCallback( OnLoad );

</script>
<div id="content">Loading...</div>

<?php
    define('Mecab_Encoding', 'SJIS');
    define('Mecab_ResultEncoding', 'UTF-8');
    define('MeCab_Path', 'mecab.exe');
    function morph_analysis($text) {
      $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, Mecab_Encoding, Mecab_ResultEncoding);
      $descriptorspec = array (
        0 => array ("pipe",   "r"), // stdin
        1 => array ("pipe", "w") // stdout
      );
      $process = proc_open(MeCab_Path, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
      if (is_resource($process)) {
        // Feed string to macab
        fwrite($pipes[0], $text);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        // Read the string
        while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
          $result .= fread($pipes[1], 4096);
        }
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        proc_close($process);

        $result = mb_convert_encoding($result, Mecab_ResultEncoding, Mecab_Encoding);
        $lines = explode("\r\n", $result);
        $res = array();
        foreach($lines as $line) {
          if(in_array(trim($line), array('EOS', ''))) {continue;}
          $s = explode("\t", $line);
          $word = $s[0];
          $words = explode(',', $s[1]);

      if ($words[0] == "名詞"){
              $res[] = array(
                'word' => $word,
                'class' => $words[0],
                'detail1' => $words[1],
                'detail2' => $words[2],
                'detail3' => $words[3],
                'conjugation1' => $words[4],
                'conjugation2' => $words[5]
              );
      }
        }
        return $res;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

$text ="今日はいい天気です。";
$result = morph_analysis($text);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to feed content loaded on the page by your javascript to your PHP script?

Comment: No, javascript is only used to put the search engine into this page.

Comment: I understand that, but this content you want to hand to your PHP script... I *assume* it's coming from the search engine API you're using and it populates the content on to your page in the div with id *content**?? Otherwise I don't understand your question.

Comment: oh, that's right, the string is in the content div and I want to hand it to the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically have a div which populates with content from your javascript API that you want to hand to PHP. The easiest way to do this is by making an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to your PHP script from javascript the same way your API is doing to populate your page. Except here you will be handing the content to PHP and getting back a result that you can then put anywhere in your page like say another **div** that you want.

```
<div id="content">Loading...</div>
```

You can access this content by using the `getElementById` property of the document with javascript.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {"text": document.getElementById('content').innerHTML },
  url: "http://www.example.com/your-php-script.php", // put the URL to your PHP script here
}).done(function ( data ) {
  document.getElementById('myOutPutDiv').innerHTML = data;
});
</script>
```

Then your HTML will have the appropriate div for output

```
<div id="myOutPutDiv">Output goes here...</div>
```

Then in your PHP script you receive the data in the $_POST/$_REQUEST super global...

```
<?php
    $text = $_POST['text']; // This is the stuff you got from your javascript

    /* Work with $text here */
```

Just be sure to separate the PHP from the javascript stuff as they will act independently.

Comment: But the 'content' will be different each time I perform a search right? It's not a URL or text so is there anyway I can put these 'content' in getElementById()?

Comment: Yes, every time you call on your API you call on your PHP script to take the new contents populated in that div and hand it to your PHP script. You have to figure out how you can set a callback on your API for when it updates the div to then take that updated div and send it off to PHP as demonstrated above.